# Отключение уведомлений telethon python

Tags: python, telethon

Здраствуйте, вопрос такой же как в шапке. Хочу отключать уведомления от чата в telethone, но ни в какую не получается. ПРобовал вот такой код:

```
result = await client(functions.account.UpdateNotifySettingsRequest(
        peer=entity.id,
        settings=types.InputPeerNotifySettings(
            mute_until=32**2
        )
    ))
```

Но это не срабатывает и уведомления остаются. Насколько знаю это вполне возможно, так как при отключении уведомлений в телеграм с одного устройства в одном чате, на других устройствах это тоже произойдет.

Зарание спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам искал решение и нашёл, вот делюсь:

**Необходимые ипорты:**

```
import datetime
from telethon.tl.types import InputPeerNotifySettings, InputNotifyPeer
from telethon.tl.functions.account import UpdateNotifySettingsRequest
```

**Объявляем в начале кода:**

```
DEFAULT_MUTE_SETTINGS = types.InputPeerNotifySettings(
silent=True,
mute_until=datetime.timedelta(days=365))
```

**Этот код вставляем там где нужно замутить чат:**

```
dialogs = await client.get_dialogs()
await client(UpdateNotifySettingsRequest(
    peer=InputNotifyPeer(entity),
    settings=DEFAULT_MUTE_SETTINGS
))
```